# Python beginner issues - dictionary

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I've been trying to produce a program with an output:

```
Enter line: which witch
Enter line: is which
Enter line: 
is 1
which 2
witch 1
```

How I want it to work is for you to enter a few lines, and when nothing is submitted it will count the number of each line.

Currently, I'm not able to count individual lines in a sentence, but only the whole sentence. My code:

```
dic = {}

while True:
    line = input('Enter Line: ')
    line = line.lower()    
    if not line:
        break

    dic.setdefault(line, 0)
    dic[line] += 1
for line, n in sorted(dic.items()):
    print(line, n)
```

Which produces output:

```
Enter line: which witch
Enter line: is which
Enter line: 
which witch 1
is which 1
```

Rather than the first one

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is using each line as a dictionary key, not word. Split lines using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and iterate words.

```
dic = {}

while True:
    line = input('Enter Line: ')
    line = line.lower()    
    if not line:
        break
    for word in line.split():    # <-----
        dic.setdefault(word, 0)  # <-----
        dic[word] += 1           # <-----
for line, n in sorted(dic.items()):
    print(line, n)
```

BTW, consider using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this kind of task (counting occurrences).

Comment: ...or use `dic[word] = dic.get(word, 0) + 1` instead of the two lines with `setdefault` (which itself calls `get()` anyway and returns a value that you're not using).

Comment: Thanks. I was spending forever on this!